# Php echo user's info only when elements are in common from sql

Tags: php, sql, database

I'm trying to make all elements from the `classlist` to display only when they are in common with me and person b. for example if I  have classes in position 1,2,5, and I'm on person b's profile who is in class 9,1,8,17,3, It would display ONLY 1 since they both have 1 in their `classlist`

[image]
<sub>(source: [goawaymom.com](http://goawaymom.com/list.png))</sub>

I've tried a few things like exploding the `classlist` and giving everything their own variable... Nothing seems to work and I am over complicating everything i try. 
Does anyone know any simple ways to do this?

```
<?php
if ($_SESSION['classlist'] == $user_info['classlist']) {
echo ($user_info['classlist']);

} else {
    echo 'No Common Classes';
}
?>
```

The above code only displays the `classlist` when the order of the `classlist` of person a and b have the same classes in the same order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[array_intersect](http://php.net/array_intersect)

For example:

```
// fetch your results from the database
$myclasses = explode(',', $myrow['classlist']);
$theirclasses = explode(',', $theirrow['classlist']);

$common_classes = array_intersect($myclasses, $theirclasses);
```

Or in your case: (assuming that both $_SESSION['classlist'] and $user_info['classlist'] are strings containing comma separated numbers: '1,2,3,4,5')

```
$myclasses = explode(',', $_SESSION['classlist']);
$theirclasses = explode(',', $user_info['classlist']);
$common_classes = array_intersect($myclasses, $theirclasses);

if (count($common_classes) > 0)
{
    echo '<p>You have the following classes in common.</p>';
    echo '<ul>';
    foreach ($common_classes as $class)
    {
        echo '<li>' . $class . '</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}
else
{
    echo '<p>Billy no mates :(</p>';
}
```

Comment: Hmmm this is the type of answer I was looking for however both 
the shared classes 'you have shared classes' and 'you dont' doesn't seem to work.... It always thinks that I have shared classes.

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding you correct maybe this would work

```
// $_SESSION[ 'classlist' ] = 9,1,8,17,3,
// $user_info[ 'classlist' ] = 1,2,5

$a_session = explode( ",", $_SESSION[ 'classlist' ]);
$a_user_info = explode( ",", $user_info[ 'classlist' ]);
$common_classes = array();

foreach( $a_session as $key => $value )
{
    if( isset($value)===TRUE && $value != NULL && trim($value) != '' )
    {
        if( in_array( $value, $a_user_info ) === TRUE )
        {
            $k = array_search( $value, $a_user_info);
            $common_classes[] = $a_user_info[ $k ];
        }
    }
}

var_dump( $common_classes );
```